# Ruby Oj parser memory issues

Tags: ruby, json, parsing, ubuntu

I've been working on a project which basically converts some json data into ruby objects to perform some tasks. The tasks side is ok, I've had some problems with the json parser.

Ruby OJ is the parser engine. It works very well when parsing no more than 1000 users data from my couchdb, but when it is over 4000, it starts to leak memory and my ubuntu server just kill the ruby process.

I'm running out of options here. I've executed just this part of the software to test its performance and found out that the parser itself is causing this issues. The code is just a **Oj.load(json)**, and each user can have at least 100 and at most 9000 lines of json data. Is that too much?

I'm testing on ruby 1.9.2 and 1.9.3.

Any clue about what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Have you tried using `Yajl` to see how much of a different will it make? I know the `Ruby OJ` is supposed to be much faster, but since you already said that are running out of options.